# What would "taken her in two senses, grateful for the tip" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I encountered the boldfaced expression while reading, and would like to know what it means:

> He took his face away from the casing and turned to climb the ladders
> to the bridge. There must be acres of the stuff spread on the
> child-time rocks at Tresellyn. That was where Nat had taken her—**taken
> her in two senses, grateful for the tip**.

- William Golding, *Pincher Martin*, Chapter 7

I vaguely assume "in two senses" would mean that Nat took (had) her in two meanings. But I cannot grasp what "grateful for the tip" would mean, though I feel it would explain what those "two senses" might be.

Comment: Did someone suggest to him something here? The idea is probably explained by something earlier in the text.

Comment: Without knowing the story, I would understand it to mean that Nat had both accompanied her there and had sex with her there, grateful either that it was a suitable place for such a liaison or that she might have sex with him - or both.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. Earlier in the text, the narrator wanted to have sex with Mary (I guess Mary means "her" here.) but then, later, his friend Nat appears to share the news that he and Mary are going to be married.
So "take" here would have two meanings, in that Nat accompanied (=took) her to the place, and Nat had (=took) her there by having sex with her. In that case, would it be okay to think that "tip" here means "hint" perhaps, rather than money given to waiters at restaurants...?